# Easy way of creating a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I want to ask about tricks for creating a stored procedure.

When I try to create the procedure, I have to write the fields at the beginning of the `@` sign - so I do not have an easy way to do this?

Like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_Vehicle_Procedure]
    (@VehiclePlateNo varchar(max),
     @Variety varchar(max)
    )
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Vehicles] ([VehiclePlateNo], [Variety])
    VALUES (@VehiclePlateNo, @Variety)
```

Sometimes there are hundreds of areas to write them can be really annoying :)

Comment: This stored procedure is pretty concise already, what exactly are you looking to "optimize" here?  I suppose you could make your variable/entity/etc. names *shorter*, but you'll quickly find diminishing returns with that since after a few characters these already concise names will stop effectively describing themselves.  If you just don't want to type the code then maybe some code-generating tool is what you're looking for.  Even a home-grown one.  You can query the table structure and emit your procedure text from that.

Comment: BTW `varchar` without length is the same as `varchar(1)` there. SSMS tools pack has a helper to create simple crud procedures for a table.

Comment: i know @MartinSmith I wrote that I was just an example.

Comment: @David I like to write code but sometimes it is not obvious time and I have to do it fast.So I'm asking what kind of tool is there to make it faster.So to me quick writing means to improve optimization.Isn't it ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just write a SQL script yourself that emits the stored procedure parameter data script block from querying the systables and syscolumns system tables.

Comment: Could you explain this a little more clearly? I think I'm missing information on this.I would like to improve my database knowledge if you can help in this regard.

Comment: All the column names and data types for a table are held in the SQL Server syscolumns table. If you wrote a query which selected data from the syscolumns table (i.e. selected a row for every field in your target table) you could easily get the Select statement to write a row of text like "@VehiclePlateNo varchar(max)" just from the data in systables and systypes.